# Selecting users that does not have a workgroup, only active users

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to figure out how I can select all active users that does not have a `workgroup` set.

I have the `user` table with the col `active` (1=true) to see if the user is active. BUT, one user can have multiple "roles" in the system, and each of the roles has a set of settings.

`Workgroup` is a setting in the userrolesetting, its ID is 1000. I want to get all users that is missing the workgroup or where the workgroup is null.

I've trying to go with:

```
SELECT *
FROM user U
INNER JOIN userrole R
ON R.uid = U.uid
INNER JOIN userrolesetting S
ON R.rid = S.rid
WHERE U.active = 1
```

This is totally nonsence, but I'm really confused on how to attack it.

Comment: It would help if you'd include the table definitions in your post.  Please edit the post and add the definitions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER u
  INNER JOIN USERROLE r
    ON (r.UID = u.UID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN USERROLESETTING s
    ON (s.RID = r.RID AND
        s.ID = 1000)  -- may be the wrong column name - change as needed
  WHERE u.ACTIVE = 1 AND
        s.RID IS NULL
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but how about this:

```
select * from user u
where u.active = 1
and exists(select 'x' from userrole r
            where u.uid = r.uid
              and not exists(select 'x' from userrolesetting s
                          where r.rid = s.rid
                            and s.settingid = 1000));
```

I don't know your data model, so, I'm not sure what you mean by "or where the workgroup is null"?

"workgroup" is where the settingid = 1000, right?

If you can show full descriptions of all three tables, it may be easier to understand what you're after.  The above query should return all users that have roles that do NOT have userrolesettings that have settingid=1000.

Hope that helps.